# Is it possible to set the email client to not automatically download images?

Tags: email, windows-10-mobile

On previous versions of Windows Phone (7.x, 8.x) and Windows Mobile, there was an option to not automatically download images.

Where is this option in the mail client for Windows 10 Mobile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: Outlook Mail -> Settings -> Reading -> External content -> "Automatically download..." option.

1. Enter Outlook Mail (opening any account's inbox or other pinned folder from Start screen or app list will work).
2. Tap the three dots in the bottom right, and select "Settings" from the menu.
3. Tap "Reading", and then find the "External content" section.
4. Select the account you want to change this setting for, or check the "Apply to all accounts" box.
5. Toggle the "Automatically download external images and style formats" option.
6. Hit the Back button twice to return to the folder you were viewing.